# UPDATE trigger for a table that is updating thousands of times daily on specific set of records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I'm looking for changes to a very specific subset of records from one of our corporate tables.  I realize that an update trigger would accomplish this, but it would be called thousands of times a day.

While I'm fairly proficient at SQL, T-SQL and triggers are a little outside of my normal playground.  I don't want to write something that will be running constantly and accomplishing very little (or annoy our DBA).

It seems like the solution would be a view that only pulls the rows I'm interested in and then writing a trigger based on that.  It seems like that's "bad form", which tells me there is a better way to accomplish the same thing.

I'm looking to use a trigger because I'm looking for a change in a value that will likely reset quickly.  (e.g. it will change to 1, and then change back to 0 a few hours later).

This trigger would be running on SQL SERVER EXPRESS 10.50.4000

I mostly just need a direction - not so much specific code.

Comment: We (as in your organization) should all be concerned about the continued use of an obsolete (and soon to be unsupported) version of sql server.

Comment: This is on it's way out - legacy SQL for a legacy ERP system...  It has caused it's share of frustrations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create a trigger on a view that fires on changes to the base table rows.

It is not an issue of "bad form" it is simply impossible (the only triggers allowed on views are `INSTEAD OF` triggers that don't do what you need).

A table trigger checking if a column has changed from `0` to `1` shouldn't cause massive overhead - especially if only called a few thousand times daily.

It should call the [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql) function to check if the column of interest has been changed - and if not exit immediately. Otherwise it should join the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables on primary key and check whether the new and old values for any row match the pattern you are trying to track.

Comment: Thank you - that's what I needed.  Very helpful.